# QT IFW PerformInstallationPageCallback not executed after installation

Tags: qt

I created a controller script for the Installer Framework. One routine is

```
    Controller.prototype.PerformInstallationPageCallback = function()
    {
        var isSilent = installer.value('isSilent');
        if (isSilent) {
            gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton);
            gui.clickButton(buttons.CommitButton);
        }
    }
```

I see the console output before all components are unpacked. So the button click isn't performed at the right point in time. What do I miss to finish the silent install?

Thanks